# mat-datepicker inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular-forms

This issue faced when using `mat-datepicker` inside `*ngFor`.

`mat-datepicker` requires a template reference variable `#test` in order to bind to the `input`.
Is there a direct way to take reference variables when using inside `*ngFor`, in general? I couldn't find a way.

Simple working example without `*ngFor`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="test" placeholder="Enter Date" [(ngModel)]="someDate" name="someDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="test"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #test></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

But since template `reference variables` must be unique for the whole template, you can't directly use the `mat-datepicker` for scenario when the above block is repeated inside an `*ngFor`, `test` wouldn't be unique.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Why do you need to put this #test? Maybe we can achieve what you want to do in a different way

Comment: @Powkachu Can you pls share an example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could add an index variable to your ngFor and assign the value of that index as an identifier for you datepicker. You could also make a public array of values inside the component that have a meaning like ["dtPickerOne", "dtPickerTwo"] and use those as values.

```
<div *ngFor="let t of test; let i = index;">
         <input matInput [matDatepicker]="i" placeholder="Choose a date" [attr.id]="dtPicker + i"
         [formControl]="dateFrom">
         <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="i"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
         <mat-datepicker #i></mat-datepicker>   
    </div>
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it causes weird behaviour if you try to use `i` somewhere else in the template, for example in string interpolation, you don't get `1 or 2 or 3`, you get `[object object]`. For this I had to use another `let j=index`.
It would help if there was a better way to use reference variables in template driven forms inside `*ngFor`.
Your 2nd approach seems suited for rather Reactive forms.

Comment: As referenced by @bitscanbyte, you may have to use multiple `let x=index` statements.  If you are using reactive forms with multiple date pickers, you can use `let i=index` and `[formGroupName]="i"`, and `let j=index` for the first datepicker as shown in the answer (except using j).  Then for more datepickers in the same form group, add another `let k=index` and then use k as the template reference variable, and so on.

Comment: Hi @theriddle2 I have a question which is been unanswered on date picker can you try on it please the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278503/highlight-a-particular-week-of-a-particular-month-in-angular-material-datepicker/64278675?noredirect=1#comment113734927_64278675

Answer (score 14):

I would like to point out that you can use underscore "_" as a separator if you would like to give it a more meaningful name.

Here is a working example with two way model binding.

```
<div *ngFor="let patient of patients; let i = index;">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="patientDueDate_i" placeholder="Due date" 
    [(ngModel)]="patient.dueDate">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="patientDueDate_i"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #patientDueDate_i></mat-datepicker>   
</div>
```