# Multiple date select in Angular material 7

Tags: angular, angular-material

Scenario: Need to select multiple date in the date picker in angular material.

currently this scenario is not there in the official documentation in [DatePicker Examples](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples)

Question : How can I implement the multiple date select with the material design?

I though of modifying the existing implementation of angular material, but have no idea where to start.

Any leads would be very helpful.

Comment: Use primeng Date range picker https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Comment: Yeah, thought of that, but I want to go with angular material.

Comment: I meant, I want with the material design. ngPrime uses bootstrap right.

Comment: No, its seprate. its your choice of using bootstrap

Comment: Actually this app was built using angular material. so it would be better to go in that way.

Comment: This question is outdated. Client went with single date selection. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to name the datepickers seperately like `picker1` and `picker2` like below.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Start date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="End date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

like this you can have multiple date select in single page.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, this helped me out: 
[mat-datepicker inside *ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451678/mat-datepicker-inside-ngfor).
Take an ngFor and use the index as reference for the date-picker. In case, the real index - not the datepicker's viewRef - is needed, too, the index has to be saved in another variable:

```
<div *ngFor="let date of formArray.controls; let datePickerViewRef = index; let i = index" class="date">
         <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePickerViewRef" placeholder="Choose a date" readonly [formControl]="date">
         <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePickerViewRef"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
         <mat-datepicker #datePickerViewRef></mat-datepicker>
         <button(click)="removeDate(i)">delete</button>
</div><button (click)="addDate()"></button>
```

Comment: can you add some explaination

Comment: You basically just implement a list of inputs (datepickers) with this, and the whole formArray will return you an array of dates in the end, which you want to have as I understood. So when the user wants to add a date, he will get a new datepicker input by clicking the addDate button (behind has to be a function which will push a new formcontrol into the array) and can enter the new date there.  If he wants to delete a date, he can just use the delete button visible in the example above.