# How can I make the options appear and disappear in a mats selection list?

Tags: angular, loops, material-design

I have a `mat-selection-list` with several options, I want that when selecting an option all the other options disappear and when deselecting the option, all the other options reappear.

If there is another better way to do it, I would like to know.

I have tried to place a `ngIf` in which if nothing is selected, everything appears, and if there is something selected, only the selected option is kept.

```
<mat-selection-list #flightsList [(ngModel)]="selectedFlight" (ngModelChange)="onFlightSelection($event)">
    <h3 mat-subheader>Selecciona el vuelo</h3>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let flight of flights">
        <mat-list-option [value]='flight' #option *ngIf="selectedFlight.length == 0 || option.selected">
             {{ flight.name }}
        </mat-list-option>
    </ng-container>
</mat-selection-list>
```

The selection does not work and it gives me a console error

The error is "undefined option", I suppose it is because at the moment of disappearing, there is no #option

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a `mat-select`

Comment: if there's an error... it's usually a good idea to post that error...

Comment: I add the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use a simple dropdown for that, an option to do this is with a mat-select, or a native HTML select.

But you should at least not take the one and only same #option view reference for every of the multiple, changing flight objects. Add an index to your *ngFor and take this index as reference:

```
*ngFor="let flight of flights; let i = index"
   <mat-list-option #i></mat-list-option> ....
```

Comment: There is no relation between `let i = index` and `#i`

Comment: have you ever heard of template variables? It's the same with mat-datepickers. You have to give a unique reference to the options. Check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451678/mat-datepicker-inside-ngfor